# English fantasy book with elves that, before 2012, got a bad Swedish translation

Tags: story-identification, translation

[All I know](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/article_history.php?article=Main.BlindIdiotTranslation&more=t#edit2353470) is that "the dark brethren of the elves" got translated to "de onda alfernas bröder".

> [I have seen] "the dark brethren of the elves" being translated to "de onda alfernas bröder" (brothers of the evil elves) in the official Swedish translation of a fantasy book.

But neither of those are showing any useful results in Google. Hopefully this is enough info for someone to figure it out.

Comment: Book, short story, epic poem...?

Comment: What is your evidence that this work even exists?  How do you know that English original was translated to Swedish that way?

Comment: The phrase doesn't ring a bell, but the original Swedish translation of *The Lord of the Rings* was apparently quite bad, with no new translation appearing until 2005.

Comment: @DavidW - It's a book

Comment: @Spencer - My linked source said it exists, and they seem to have compared the Swedish to the English.

Comment: I didn't find Elves mentioned anywhere in the linked page. Perhaps you should edit your post to include an excerpt, and cite the person making the claim. Links have a way of breaking and so it's important to include all of the relevant information in the post itself.

Comment: @Spencer - If that link breaks, I'll have more problems than just this. Does your browser not automatically scroll down with anchor links? Gonna see how to convert the info to StackExchange style.

Comment: I've got 2 close hits on the English, but I can't find any evidence either was translated into Swedish.

Comment: @Malady The link doesn't show any mention of _dark brethren_ for me either. Maybe you need to have an account on TVTropes to see it. However the paragraph you cite [is present on this page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/BlindIdiotTranslation/Literature) about 60% of the way down the page. Maybe you could change the link to this page so everyone can see it.

Comment: The [Fever series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41192-fever) by Karen Marie Moning mentions the _dark brethren of the Fae_ and has been translated into multiple languages. However I cannot find a Swedish translation.

Comment: @JohnRennie - The issue being that only the link I use has the time info about it being pre-2012. Sure seems like multiple browers have issues with anchor links, since testing on Android Outlook's browser has the same issue.

Comment: I imagine it could be *The Lord of the Rings*, given that orcs are dark, twisted verions of elves. However, Google can't find the exact phrase.